# Will scikit-learn utilize GPU?

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, k-means, neuraxle

Reading implementation of scikit-learn in TensorFlow: http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson6/ and scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html I'm struggling to decide which implementation to use.

scikit-learn is installed as part of the tensorflow docker container so can use either implementation.

Reason to use scikit-learn :

> scikit-learn contains less boilerplate than the tensorflow
> implementation.

Reason to use tensorflow :

> If running on Nvidia GPU the algorithm will be run against in parallel
> , I'm not sure if scikit-learn will utilize all available GPUs?

Reading https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-differences-between-TensorFlow-and-SciKit-Learn

> TensorFlow is more  low-level; basically, the Lego bricks that help
> you to implement machine learning algorithms whereas scikit-learn
> offers you off-the-shelf algorithms, e.g., algorithms for
> classification such as SVMs, Random Forests, Logistic Regression, and
> many, many more. TensorFlow shines if you want to implement
> deep learning algorithms, since it allows you to take advantage of
> GPUs for more efficient training.

This statement re-enforces my assertion that "scikit-learn contains less boilerplate than the tensorflow implementation" but also suggests scikit-learn will not utilize all available GPUs?

Comment: The classic scikit-learn lib is cpu-only, as indicated in the [FAQs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support) (**edit:** did not saw this ref in the answer, sry). (Also every bit of sklearn code i checked is not ready for GPU)

Comment: NVIDIA have released [their own version](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/) of sklearn with GPU support.

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Tensorflow only uses GPU if it is built against Cuda and CuDNN. By default it does not use GPU, especially if it is running inside Docker, unless you use [nvidia-docker](https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker) and an image with a built-in support.

Scikit-learn is not intended to be used as a deep-learning framework and  it does not provide any GPU support.

> **Why is there no support for deep or reinforcement learning / Will there be support for deep or reinforcement learning in scikit-learn?**
>
> Deep learning and reinforcement learning both require a rich
> vocabulary to define an architecture, with deep learning additionally
> requiring GPUs for efficient computing. However, neither of these fit
> within the design constraints of scikit-learn; as a result, deep
> learning and reinforcement learning are currently out of scope for
> what scikit-learn seeks to achieve.

Extracted from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#why-is-there-no-support-for-deep-or-reinforcement-learning-will-there-be-support-for-deep-or-reinforcement-learning-in-scikit-learn

> **Will you add GPU support in scikit-learn?**
>
> No, or at least not in the near future. The main reason is that GPU
> support will introduce many software dependencies and introduce
> platform specific issues. scikit-learn is designed to be easy to
> install on a wide variety of platforms. Outside of neural networks,
> GPUs don’t play a large role in machine learning today, and much
> larger gains in speed can often be achieved by a careful choice of
> algorithms.

Extracted from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support

Comment: NVIDIA have released [their own version](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/) of sklearn with GPU support.

Answer (score 17):

I'm experimenting with a drop-in solution (h2o4gpu) to take advantage of GPU acceleration in particular for Kmeans:

try this:

```
from h2o4gpu.solvers import KMeans
#from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

as of now, version 0.3.2 still don't have *.inertia*_ but I think it's in their [TODO](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o4gpu/latest-stable/h2o4gpu-py-docs/html/_modules/h2o4gpu/solvers/kmeans.html) list.

EDIT: Haven't tested yet, but [scikit-cuda](https://github.com/lebedov/scikit-cuda) seems to be getting traction.

EDIT: [RAPIDS](https://rapids.ai) is really the way to go here.

Comment: More specifically, the [cuML](https://docs.rapids.ai/api/cuml/stable/) project under RAPIDS is a mirror of sklearn with GPU support.

Answer (score 8):

From my experience, I use [this package](https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex) to utilize GPU for some sklearn algorithms in [here](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/algorithms.html).

The code I use:

```
import numpy as np
import dpctl
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn, config_context
patch_sklearn()

from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN

X = np.array([[1., 2.], [2., 2.], [2., 3.],
            [8., 7.], [8., 8.], [25., 80.]], dtype=np.float32)
with config_context(target_offload="gpu:0"):
    clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(X)
```

Source: [oneAPI and GPU support in Intel(R) Extension for Scikit-learn](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/gpu.html)