# Is scikit-learn running on my GPU?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gpu, nvidia

This question is related to [Will scikit-learn utilize GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567895/will-scikit-learn-utilize-gpu) but I don't think offers same answer. I'm executing scikit-learn algorithms against an Nvidia GPU without error so assume scikit is running on the underlying hardware. As scikit-learn is not designed to execute against GPU what is process that enables the algorithms to run ?

For example I'm running executing scikit-learn algorithms using `Gigabyte Nvidia GTX 1060 WF2 3GB GDDR5 PCI-E` with spec :

```
1152 NVIDIA CUDA Cores
1582MHz Base/1797MHz Boost Clock (OC Mode) or 1556MHz Base/1771MHz Boost Clock (Gaming Mode)
3GB GDDR5 8008MHz Memory
```

Using scikit-learn are some of the cores not being executed against ?

Update :

I use Nvidia docker container to run container on GPU as specified : https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker. I've installed scikit on this container so `scikit-learn` algorithms are being executed on GPU ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are you asking where sklearn is being run as it's not running on the GPU? sklearn runs on the CPU.

Comment: @olieidel please see update

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will scikit-learn utilize GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567895/will-scikit-learn-utilize-gpu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

scikit-learn does not and can not run on the GPU. See [this answer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#will-you-add-gpu-support) in the scikit-learn FAQ.

Comment: how do you measure that scikit-learn is running on your GPU? It is not. It's impossible.

Comment: @blue-sky You should read some introduction to Docker if you think running a docker-container build for GPU-support does mean: *anything which runs inside my container, will run on GPU*, which is wrong by the way.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, I use [this package](https://intelpython.github.io/daal4py/) to utilize GPU for some sklearn algorithms in [here](https://intelpython.github.io/daal4py/algorithms.html).

The code I use:

```
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
from daal4py.oneapi import sycl_context
patch_sklearn()
```

Source: [oneAPI and GPU support in Intel(R) Extension for Scikit-learn](https://intel.github.io/scikit-learn-intelex/gpu.html)