# SKLearn RFE (Recursive Feature Elimination) over GPUs

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, gpu, rfe

I am wondering if there's support for RFE execution over GPUs
From what I checked in sklearn site, I couldn't find any documentation for that, therefore, I assume there's no official support. [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html]

If there are some pointers to either official support, or any academic/non-academic attempts, would appreciate the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SKLearn does not support GPU utilization for any of their functions. You can find more about that here: [Will scikit-learn utilize GPU?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567895/will-scikit-learn-utilize-gpu)